# Compiling and running Java, with bundled dependencies

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath, javac, buildpath

### Context

I need to utilize Websockets, but the ancient version of PHP we're using doesn't support them. I've decided to try a Java Websocket server. I've written a handful of Android applications in Android Studio, so I'm familiar with the basic syntax of Java, but have very little experience compiling and running java-things manually.

I'd like the server to be a single file that I can run once from the command line and forget about. To that end, I've decided to use [this library](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) which includes a Javascript chat app in the examples. I'm having trouble compiling and running the server for the example.

I'm on a Mac.

### What I tried

1. Copy the server (`src/main/example/ChatServer.java`) to the directory with the rest of the dependencies (`/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/`).
2. Move into the library directory: `cd ./src/main/java/org/java_websocket/`
3. compile all library .java files and the ChatServer file into a jar: `jar cfv ChatServer.jar *`
4. Run it: `java ChatServer`
5. Receive error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ChatServer

### Question

How can I compile `ChatServer.java` with all the dependencies into a single file that can be copied to the server and executed with a single command?

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven or Gradle. Since you've done Android apps, you're probably familiar with Gradle, so I'd recommend trying that one first.

Comment: Yeah, but AS takes care of all the Gradle stuff. All I've ever done with Gradle is add dependencies to the `build.gradle` file and hit the "build" button. I Googled and found a few tutorials, some suggesting that I need something called `FatJar` but all the tutorials seem to differ pretty dramatically. Would you mind elaborating a little bit? What should my build.gradle file look like?